# How to create nested arrays of dictionaries

Tags: ios, objective-c

I currently have data in an array of dictionaries which looks like the following:

```
Category    SubCategory    ItemID  ItemName  ItemDetails
Category 1  Subcategory 1  Item1ID Item1Name Item1Details
Category 1  Subcategory 1  Item2ID Item2Name Item2Details
Category 1  Subcategory 2  Item1ID Item1Name Item1Details
Category 1  Subcategory 2  Item2ID Item2Name Item2Details
Category 1  Subcategory 2  Item3ID Item3Name Item3Details
Category 2  Subcategory 1  Item1ID Item1Name Item1Details
Category 2  Subcategory 2  Item1ID Item1Name Item1Details
Category 2  Subcategory 2  Item2ID Item2Name Item2Details etc
```

Rather than being tabular, the data needs to be hierarchical so that there are an array of categories filled with arrays of subcategories filled with arrays of the lowest level data - the info on the items (ItemID, ItemName, ItemDetails).

Given each category has a name (e.g. from above - Category 1) and an array of subcategories and each subcategory has a name and an array of items then I assume it needs the following structure:

```
Category array
contains Dictionary with two keys:
a string with the category name
an array of subcategories

Subcategory array
contains Dictionary with two keys:
a string with the category name
an array of items

Item dictionary
is a dictionary with three keys:
ItemID, ItemName, ItemDetails
```

How would I populate the new structure using the array of dictionaries?  I have started it below with a for loop that loops through the array of dictionaries but really unsure how to create the right objects at the right time given there are three levels of information.

```
categories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(ItemDictionary* i in ItemDictionaryArray)
{
      //create new category entry
      NSMutableDictionary *categoryDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithCapacity:2];
    [categoryDict setObject:[NSString stringWithString:currentCategory] forKey:@"Category"];
    [categoryDict setObject:subcategories forKey:@"Subcategories"];
    [categories addObject:categoryDict];
}
```

Really appreciate any assistance.
Rob

Comment: Are you asking a syntax question? (How do I convert X to Y?) Or a question about how to structure your data? It's not really clear to me what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear, it was a syntax question regarding how to convert to a nested array of dictionaries.  I did also ask the other question, if I was structuring the data correctly, in case I was asking for the answer to the wrong question.

Comment: Can you please post an example set of data that you're starting with, and what format you'd like it to be in when you're done?

Comment: The example set of data is already there in the box and the format was also stated - "Category[0][0][0] and Category[0][0][1] giving the dictionary values of ItemID, ItemName and ItemDetails for the first two entries in the sample data then the next entry would be Category[0][1][0] for the first item in the second subcategory." but have posted how I solved it

Answer (score 0):

Well it took a while to realise that there isn't any way to instantiate an array of arrays which is why I couldn't find it anywhere.  You just need to insert an array into another one as though it was any other kind of object.  So the code I used to create the nested arrays is:

```
NSMutableArray *categories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < numCategories; i++) {
  NSMutableArray *subcategories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  for (int j = 0; j < numSubcategories; j++) {
    NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [subcategories addObject:items];
  }
  [categories addObject:subcategories];
}
```

Comment: Since you know how big they'll need to be, you may want to use `initWithCapacity:` for some free (albeit usually minimal) performance gains.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I don't actually know that, this was just the first part of the solution that involved creating nested arrays as I had no idea how to do that.  I'll edit the main question now to make it more focused